# Time between receiving packets in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

I'm using Scapy for a project and one of the requirements is that I need to sniff packets and send requests containing data from each packet to a website in order to get certain data. No problem so far.

There is a catch: I can only send to the website a certain number of requests per hour, otherwise it blocks me. I need to send every request the moment I sniff a new packet.

Here's what I have currently (no need to get too deep into what's in here):

`from scapy.all import *
.
.
.
packets = sniff(lfilter = is_valid_ip, prn = print_the_ip_that_is_not_me)`

Is there any way to delay or wait between every packet without adding an external function? I know I can just add a `sleep()` in one of the functions (`is_valid_ip` or `print_the_ip_that_is_not_me`), but right now I'm only looking for something to put inside the `sniff()` itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

scapy itself provides an option of delay while sending a packet. You can select any value of `inter` and it will provide delay in seconds. For example, if you want to send a packet at layer 3.

```
send(pkt, inter=0)
```

or you can do it for layer 2.

```
sendp(x, inter=0)
```